# Getting XML Data with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I can not write XML data into my HTML page. It seems it's not even reading, because it doesn't even alert. What part am I missing ?

My XML:

```
<ProgramOgrenmeCiktilari>

    <Category>
        <TopTitle> Bilgi </TopTitle>
        <Title> Kuramsal, Olgusal </Title>
        <Text>- Matematik, fen bilimleri ve ilgili mühendislik disiplinine özgü konularda yeterli bilgi birikimi;...
             </Text>
    </Category>

    <Category>
        <TopTitle> Beceriler </TopTitle>
        <Title> Bilişsel, Uygulamalı </Title>
        <Text>- Karmaşık bir sistemi, süreci, cihazı veya ürünü gerçekçi kısıtlar ve koşullar altında,...
            </Text>
    </Category>

    <Category>
        <TopTitle> Yetkinlikler </TopTitle>
        <Title> Bağımsız Çalışabilme ve Sorumluluk Alabilme Yetkinliği </Title>
        <Text>- Disiplin içi ve çok disiplinli...</Text>
    </Category>

</ProgramOgrenmeCiktilari>
```

jQuery part

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    /* here goes some other codes about other buttons... */

    $("#program").click(function () {
        $.get('ProgramOgrenmeCiktilari.xml', function (data) {
            $(xml).find('Category').each(function () {
                var TopTitle = $(this).find('TopTitle').text();
                var Title = $(this).find('Title').text();
                var Text = $this.find('Text').text();

                var html = '<tr>   <td colspan="3" style="background-color:#DFE4FF;"><b>TopTitle     </b></td> </tr> ';
                html += '<tr> <td><br> <b>Title</b> <br><br>Text <br><br></td></tr><tr>';

                $(".kutu_icerik").html(data);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Sounds like the response is not 200 OK. Have you checked the network tab to inspect the state of the request? It will tell you if it worked, and if it did not, why.

Comment: http://imgur.com/j6v2eNJ Yes, it seems working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if response is `200 ok`
It be `$(data).find('Category').each(function(){` instead of `$(xml).find('Category').each(function(){`
and

```
var html = '<tr><td colspan="3" style="background-color:#DFE4FF;"><b>+'TopTitle'+</b>/td> </tr> ';
html += '<tr> <td><br> <b>'+Title+'</b> <br><br>='+Text'+<br><br></td></tr>';
$(".kutu_icerik").html(html);
```

instead of `$(".kutu_icerik").html(data);`

Comment: Thanks, it should be working but no data is being shown on the html page. I think this is a matter of mine.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you work with an HTML templating library like [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/). These libraries help you generate HTML from structured data (objects and arrays).

Sou your task would be to generate objects and arrays from the input XML and write a basic template that handlebars can use. Handlebars will then do the tedious part of HTML generation.

Advantages:

- Much cleaner JS code.
- Much less to to go wrong (especially when it comes to escaping data properly).
- HTML templates live where all your other HTML is.

```js
// prepare the template (you only need to do this once)
var categoryTemplate = Handlebars.compile($("#Category-template").html());

// this is what the server returns
var xml = "<ProgramOgrenmeCiktilari>\
    <Category>\
        <TopTitle> Bilgi </TopTitle>\
        <Title> Kuramsal, Olgusal </Title>\
        <Text>- Matematik, fen bilimleri ve ilgili mühendislik disiplinine özgü \konularda yeterli bilgi birikimi;...\
             </Text>\
    </Category>\
    <Category>\
        <TopTitle> Beceriler </TopTitle>\
        <Title> Bilişsel, Uygulamalı </Title>\
        <Text>- Karmaşık bir sistemi, süreci, cihazı veya ürünü gerçekçi kısıtlar ve koşullar altında,...\
            </Text>\
    </Category>\
    <Category>\
        <TopTitle> Yetkinlikler </TopTitle>\
        <Title> Bağımsız Çalışabilme ve Sorumluluk Alabilme Yetkinliği </Title>\
        <Text>- Disiplin içi ve çok disiplinli...</Text>\
    </Category>\
</ProgramOgrenmeCiktilari>";

// in the Ajax success callback...
var categories = $(xml).find('Category').map(function () {
    return {
        TopTitle: $(this).find('TopTitle').text(),
        Title: $(this).find('Title').text(),
        Text: $(this).find('Text').text()
    };
}).toArray();

$(".kutu_icerik tbody").html(categoryTemplate(categories));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<script id="Category-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each .}}
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="background-color:#DFE4FF;">
      <b>{{TopTitle}}</b>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <b>{{Title}}</b>
      <br>
      <br>{{Text}}
    </td>
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
</script>

<table class="kutu_icerik">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh thank you sir, even if i solved the problem that was a pretty expert information for a dumb question to use for the future. I appreciate for your time.